# Difference between 2 times should give some value

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
Time in     Time out    Total Time    Total
11:13 AM    11:18 AM    0:05:00
```

So here the difference between total time is 5 mins so in the total it should show 10
(or if the if the difference between time is 40mins it should show 10).

And if the time difference between time is from 41mins to 70mins (i.e 1hr 10mins)  it should show 15.

What formula do I put in the total column to do this?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: WHY? Why should a time difference of 5 minutes show as 10?? And a difference of 40 minutes also show 10?? You need to explain your logic. Better yet, post a link to a sample file with the desired results entered manually and explain the processing logic.

Comment: Without some explanation to the seemingly arbitrary choice of values required in the total column this is not particularly easy to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a little table for those references and use a `VLOOKUP()`:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,F:G,2)
```

[image]

As from 0 mins to just before 41 mins (40 mins), give 10.
As from 41 mins to just before 1h11min (70 mins), give 15.
You can put something in cell G4 and this will go to cell D6. For example, if you put 20 there, the formula will pick it, and will give any other times in column C above 1h10min that value.